# File doesn't exists when i select a gallery photo android

Tags: android, file, select, gallery, photo

When I select an image from the gallery, I grab the intent Uri via the parameter that is passed by the onActivityResult. When doing: new File(String_Uri_given_to_me) and do File.Exists(), gives me null...
What I can do?

Comment: can you post exception where you have got a null or paste your code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you may try:
new File(Uri_given_to_you.getpath())

It may be okay.

Answer (score 0):

If answer above doesn't solve your problem use this code

```
private final synchronized String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String res = null;
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, proj,
            null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        res = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a hard time with this issue. I was not able to get some images Path (Even using Maxim Efivmov code) and finally decided to use Google's documentation on this topic. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html

This piece of code worked to get the bitmap

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
    ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
    getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
    FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
    parcelFileDescriptor.close();
    return image;
}
```

You can use this bitmap to display it in an Image View.